# Fixing a bug when running rest-client

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying to require `rest-client` on Windows, but I do encounter this error:

> cannot load file --ffi

How to hack needed files to make `rest-client` executable, so that I can perform some requests?

Thanks so much for solution.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error(I recommend to those working on theodinproject using windows 7)

just do this

1. gem uninstall ffi
2. gem install ffi --platform=ruby